# Tail pointer for overwrite functionality in circular buffer implementation

Tags: c, circular-buffer, dmesg

I am trying to implement a circular buffer for logging messages. I have implemented a fairly basic solution which seems to work but I am confused about how push should work in real case scenario. Should head overwrite the tail? if yes do we modify the tail to reflect it to point to next oldest log?

/******************************************************************************

```
                        Online C Compiler.
            Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
```

Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

/******************************************************************************

```
                        Online C Compiler.
            Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
```

Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LOG_SIZE 10
typedef struct{
  char *buffer[LOG_SIZE];
  int16_t head;
  int16_t tail;
  int16_t count;
  volatile bool full_status;
  volatile bool empty_status;
}circbuff;

pthread_mutex_t circMutex;
void circbuff_reset(circbuff *circ_b)
{
  circ_b->head = 0;
  circ_b->tail =0;
  circ_b->full_status =  false;
  circ_b->count =0;
  circ_b->empty_status =  false;
}
circbuff * circbuff_init ()
{
  circbuff *my_circ_buff = (circbuff *) malloc(sizeof(circbuff));
  circbuff_reset(my_circ_buff);
  return (my_circ_buff);
}

void push(circbuff *circ_b, char* message)
{

  pthread_mutex_lock(&circMutex);
  if (!circ_b->full_status)
  {
    //circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] =  (char*)malloc(strlen(message)+1);
    circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] = strdup(message);
    //printf ("Value inserted at position %d is %s and count %d\r\n", circ_b->head, circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head],circ_b->count);
    circ_b->head = (circ_b->head + 1) % LOG_SIZE;
    if(circ_b->head==circ_b->tail)
        circ_b->full_status=true;
    circ_b->empty_status=false;
    circ_b->count++ ; 
  }
  else //can be changed to overwrite
  {

    free(circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head]);
    circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] = strdup(message);
    //printf ("Value inserted at position %d is %s and count %d\r\n", circ_b->head, circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head],circ_b->count);
    circ_b->head = (circ_b->head + 1) % LOG_SIZE;
     circ_b->tail = (circ_b->tail + 1) % LOG_SIZE;
    if(circ_b->head==circ_b->tail)
        circ_b->full_status=true;
    circ_b->empty_status=false;
     
      //printf("Cant push logs\n");
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&circMutex);
}

char* pop(circbuff *circ_b)
{

  pthread_mutex_lock(&circMutex);
  if (!circ_b->empty_status)
  {
    //printf ("Value read at position %d is %s and count %d\r\n", circ_b->tail, circ_b->buffer[circ_b->tail],circ_b->count);
    char* pop_value = circ_b->buffer[circ_b->tail]; //-->free after this? 
   
    circ_b->tail = (circ_b->tail + 1) % LOG_SIZE;
    if(circ_b->head==circ_b->tail)
        circ_b->empty_status=true;
    circ_b->count--;
     circ_b->full_status=false;
    return pop_value;
  }
  else
  return "Empty Buffer";
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&circMutex);
}


int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&circMutex,NULL);
    circbuff* myBuffer = circbuff_init();
    char buff[20];
    scanf("%s", buff);
    push(myBuffer, buff);
    scanf("%s", buff);
    push(myBuffer, buff);

    char *tmp;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < 2; i++)
    {
        tmp = pop(myBuffer);
        printf("%s-popped\n",tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&circMutex);

}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of 'volatile' on those 2 bools?

Comment: It was something I thought about earlier that since push/ pop could called simultaneously (in multithreaded env) I want the value used while checking to be current. But not sure if I really need it though since for multi threaded I would have to add mutex anyways

Comment: The number of people who need to use `volatile` is far smaller than the number of people who use it.

Comment: you do not need them, even in a multithreaded version of this code, for a MT version you need to worry about waaaay more things in this code (like 2 people updating the node count at once)

Answer (score 1):

This code is very broken.

```
circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] = (char*)malloc(strlen(message)+1);
circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] = message;
```

You seem to think that the second line will copy the message into the space you just malloced. It will not; all you did was leak the memory you just allocated. You simply replace the pointer returned by malloc with the message pointer.

Use `strdup` it will malloc and copy for you.

Second, when the circle is full you need to free up the old node's message as well as allocate a new one.

Can you run this code on a Linux desktop? If so, run it under Valgrind, it will reveal all your leaks.

Those 'volatiles' are meaningless too.

To show that the current code is not working I made a different main

```
int main(){

      circbuff* myBuffer = circbuff_init(10);
      char buff[20];
      scanf("%s", buff);
      push(myBuffer, buff);
      scanf("%s", buff);
      push(myBuffer, buff);


    for(int i = 0 ;i < 2; i++)
    printf("%s-popped\n",pop(myBuffer));

}
```

ran it and got

```
hello1
Value inserted at position 0 is hello1
hello2
Value inserted at position 1 is hello2
Value read at position 0 is hello2  <<<<======
hello2-popped
Value read at position 1 is hello2
hello2-popped
```

you see you got hello2 out twice

and here is valgrinds output

```
==4752== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4752==     in use at exit: 94 bytes in 3 blocks
==4752==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 2 frees, 2,142 bytes allocated
==4752==
==4752== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==4752==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4752==    by 0x109282: push (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==    by 0x10971B: main (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==
==4752== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==4752==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4752==    by 0x109282: push (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==    by 0x109746: main (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==
==4752== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==4752==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4752==    by 0x109221: circbuff_init (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==    by 0x1096EC: main (in /home/pm100/ut/a.out)
==4752==
==4752== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4752==    definitely lost: 94 bytes in 3 blocks
==4752==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4752==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4752==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4752==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4752==
==4752== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the memory leak.                                                                                         So I think something like this would be the right way to do it in push(full buffer case)                                 
 
    free(circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head]);
    circ_b->buffer[circ_b->head] = strdup(message);

Comment: @PriyankPandya note that you r code does not work either , look at the output from my test main

Comment: I think now I am seeing the right output checked with your main. While overwriting logs I can free the previous allocated memory and assign new memory (using strdup) but in case for pop api I cannot free in the same api so one way is to free is from the main function where pop is called from. Is this the right way to handle free?

Comment: @PriyankPandya you should free in pop too

Comment: how can I free in pop since I am returning the pointer to the main and printing the  from the pointer ?

Comment: @PriyankPandya ok for pop then, you must return a pointer and the caller must free the message when they are done with it

Comment: thanks for the clarifications. I have edited my code above based on your comments.

Comment: @PriyankPandya note that you are not unlocking in pop

Comment: @PriyankPandya life would be so much easier for you in c++

Comment: I am unlocking in pop(after else) . What advantage would I get in implementing this on C++ vs C?

Comment: @PriyankPandya you never reach the unlock, you return before it always. The unlock is unreachable

Comment: @PriyankPandya c++ has std::string and std::mutex. std::mutex does scope based unlocks (which is what you are hoping for in pop), std::string will free automatically